# Angular 2: 2 Single Page apps for one web app

Tags: angular

I am working on a web based application which can have two types of users -- sellers and buyer. For sellers we have completely different view and for buyers we have different. But entities are same for both and I need same services on both sides. I want to have routing like the following

mydomain.com/login, mydomain.com/categoryName/productName

and on seller side I want to have routing like

mydomain.com/seller/dashboard

One user can have both roles -- buyer and seller. SO if you login as buyer you will not have to login again to access seller area.

My question is how I should create the structure. I have already created buyer module and have pretty nice components. But I am wondering how reuse my services and how to create route as I have mentioned above. I understand I need to create another module for seller side, but not sure how I to link them? I tried creating two htmls and redirection mechanism but to me it doesn't look neat.

Answer (score 0):

This is just 1 Single Page Application.

You make 3 modules.
1 for sellers, 1 for buyers and 1 shared.
In the shared module you put stuff used by the other 2.

For security you can put different guards on your routes. So that a buyer can only see stuff from the buyer module.

More info on that here: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. So the shared module should be the entry point of the application? Or we need to create shared as NGModule and create fourth module as entry point?

Comment: Typically your first page is the login page which is in your shared module.